# Problema com Criação e localização de modulo pelo AngularJS

Tags: javascript

Observem o código;

```
<!DOCTYPE html ng-app="helloWword">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ola Mundo</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module("helloWword", []);
        angular.module("helloWword").controller("helloWwordCtrl", function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = "Ola mundo";
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="helloWwordCtrl">
    {{message}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Como vocês podem perceber estou criando o modeulo aqui nessa linha;

```
angular.module("helloWword", []);
```

E aqui estou fazendo com que o modulo seja localizado;

```
    angular.module("helloWword").controller("helloWwordCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "ESTA APARECENDO NO SITE";
    });
</script>
```

e pela linha de código era para parecer **ESTA APARECENDO NO SITE** em tela do navegador, sendo que não é isso que acontece, ele simplesmente aparece **{{message}}**

O que será que fiz de errado?

Comment: angular 1.x ou 2.x?

Comment: Já experimentas-te com o `ng-app="helloWword"` no `<body>`? funciona para mim... http://jsfiddle.net/s8wp9pob/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu erro está nas duas primeiras linhas:

```
<!DOCTYPE html ng-app="helloWword">
<html>
```

Você precisa declarar a app no inicio do `html` e não na declaração do tipo de arquivo. Embora uma melhor prática seja declarar o `ngApp`  no `body` como o Sergio♦ já comentou. Para funcionar o código deveria ser algo como:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="helloWorld">
<head>
  <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="teste">
    {{message}}
  </div>

  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var app = angular.module("helloWorld", []);

  app.controller('teste', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Hello from the other side!!";
  });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gostaria de tira uma dúvida, tem como ter thymeleaf e AngularJS no mesmo projeto? eu acho que não tem como porque é necessário colocar as tag´s de thymeleaf para funcionar e no mesmo lugar que colocar as tag´s do thymeleaf é o mesmo lugar onde coloca a tag do AngularJS, se colocar a tag´s do thymeleaf o AngularJS não funciona.